# Monitor unlimited files/folders under Mac osx with Qt

Tags: qt, file-monitoring

I am working on an application targeted to **Mac OSX 10.6+** using **Qt 4.7.4**

I have a folder with as much as 1000 files + and some or many or even all of these files may be renamed or moved or deleted, so I want to report to my application if:

1. File is renamed (report original and renamed filename)
2. Folder renamed (report original and renamed folder name)
3. File/folder is deleted (just report it as deleted)/moved (report the moved location)

**PROBLEM:** is the underlying system may (its MAY) only allow 256 descriptors to be monitored so at most 256 files! How can I over come this?

Note: used `QFileSystemWatcher` interface (it has the above stated problem)

ALSO : How to handle in case of version lower than OSX 10.5

Do mention how do i get renamed filename/foldername

Answer (score 1):

From the [`QFileSystemWatcher`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfilesystemwatcher.html) docs:

> On Mac OS X 10.4 and all BSD variants, for example, an open file descriptor is required for each monitored file. Some system limits the number of open file descriptors to 256 by default. This means that addPath() and addPaths() will fail if your process tries to add more than 256 files or directories to the file system monitor. Also note that your process may have other file descriptors open in addition to the ones for files being monitored, and these other open descriptors also count in the total. **Mac OS X 10.5 and up use a different backend and do not suffer from this issue.**

So you should not need to worry about this at all in your case.

`QFileSystemWatcher` doesn't provide the information you requested in your edit. It will emit signals when one of the paths it monitors changes, but in case of a rename, you won't get the new name. It's intended more for things like file manager programs that will just update/reload their current view on receipt of such events.

If you need more information than that, you'll need to use OS specific APIs. You can look at the code Qt uses for different platforms in the Qt source. It's in `src/core/io/qfilsystemwatcher_*.[h|cpp]`.

For Mac OS X 10.5 or greater, the underlying API used is the [`FSEvents`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/FSEvents_ProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) API. You can read in the Technology Overview page:

> The important point to take away is that the granularity of notifications is at a directory level. It tells you only that something in the directory has changed, but does not tell you what changed.

So that OS-level API doesn't provide what you want either directly.
For older versions of Mac OS X and FreeBSD, Qt uses the [`kqueue`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man2/kqueue.2.html) API, with the `EVFILT_VNODE` event filter. That API doesn't provide the new name of a renamed file either.

In short, either you'll need to code something yourself based on one of those APIs, find a library that does it (with guarantees that meet your needs), or you'll need to redesign your application. "Watching" a directory in a portable manner is at best very tricky, and generally race- and error-prone. If I were you, I wouldn't be too optimistic especially if your design requires that no "event" be missed.

Comment: @Mat i have read that, what i inferred was that the problem of having a process associated with other file descriptors and the one the files being monitored is solved , but no comment on the 256 default limit is mentioned in the documentation

Comment: @RahulReddy: the fact that processes have limited numbers of file descriptors isn't something that Qt can address, it's an OS policy that applications cannot override (but the limits are generally tunable). The 256 limit as well as the fact that "normal" fds are counted in that limit are one and the same thing.

Comment: Qt uses a different API for 10.5 and up that (apparently) either doesn't use file descriptors, or uses only one (or a limited set) to monitor multiple paths. Before 10.4, you'll have to implement something yourself if you hit these limits. (And that's going to be race-prone, there's no safe way to do file change monitoring without OS support.)